iOS Storekit 2 remove sandbox user doesn't work
Testing with latest Xcode 16.1 and iOS 18.2 on the real device with sandbox user. I setup sandbox user as described in Apple guide. Trying to purchase product:
    func purchase(_ product: Product) async throws -> Transaction? {
    guard let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "my test uuid") else { return nil }
    let result = try await product.purchase(options: [.appAccountToken(uuid)])
    switch result {
    case .success(.verified(let transaction)):
        purchasedNonConsumables.insert(product)
        await transaction.finish()
        return transaction
    default:
        return nil
    }
}

It is working. On the device I see request with credentials for sandbox user etc. I need to reset purchases and it is not working at all, tried to delete sandbox user, but purchase still working. I am delete sandbox user in app connect and purchase is still working, so no request for new user etc.

Did you try to clear purchase history in your sandbox account?

yes sure, not working

Please contact Apple about this. It's a bug at their end. There's nothing we can do about it. I've complained about it; you should complain about it too.
